# How to list all available Mono runtimes

Tags: mono

I want to see what Mono runtimes are installed on my Ubuntu 2014.04.
How to do?

For now it is just trial-and-error:

```
mono --runtime=v2.0.50727 -> OK
mono --runtime=v3.0       -> KO
mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 -> OK
```

Where can I see the list of numbers like 4.0.30319 that are OK?

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but maybe this helps.  From a terminal window,

```
gacutil -l | less
```

will list all of the assemblies in the Global Assembly Cache which is where the framework lives.  The list includes the version numbers.  My 14.04 install appears to contain versions 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0.  Note that these numbers don't include the final build number like Microsoft does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check the mono version installed on your system.

> mono --version

**OR**

> mono -V

Comment: That would only give the current preferred version of mono. If Mono uses the alternatives system, try `update-alternatives --list mono` (or whatever name the mono alternative config has)

Comment: Wrong answer. Its shows the version of `mono` itself.  Not the supported runtimes.